# transferring boolean value between two avtivities

Tags: java, android, android-intent, parameter-passing

i am developing an android application which call my Starting activity from another activity. since i am calling my 1st activity i cannot use intent to transfer a Boolean variable so i created a object of my calling activity and accessed data though it. 
like this

```
Activity1 log=new Activity1();
boolean stat=log.aResponse;
```

i checked the value of aResponse in my Activity1 its value is **true.**
but in my starting activity the value of stat is false all the time.
I tried the same code in another activity(which is not my 1st activity) in that also the value i obtain is false. anybody please help me.

Comment: You should google this first..!! see this : http://stackoverflow.com/q/2091465/6127411.

Comment: You don't ever want to instantiate an Activity manually

Comment: I'm confused as to why you can't use an `Intent`.

Comment: i cant use intent because the Activity1 is calling the 1st activity of my application. if i use an intent then i cant launch the app.

Comment: you should use bundle for passing arguments through intent please explain why can't you use intent.

Comment: there has to be a launching activity ?? isn't it??

Comment: you can still use an intent even if you want to launch your first activity..

Comment: Activity1 is calling the launching activity of the app. thats why i cant use intent.

Comment: @Vikram how do i do that?

Comment: Yeah, nobody really knows what you mean by that, or why it's preventing you from passing data with an `Intent`. You need to provide more detail.

Comment: my app launches **startingactivity**, user can login in activity1. after the login the value **aResponse** is set to true. then **activity1** calls the starting activity. from on that the value of stat determines different propertie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply call your launching activity by this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Activity1.this, StartingActivity.class);
i.putExtra("varName", variable);//values you want to carry
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: if your app is crashing using this code, please post crash logs for the possible reason..

Comment: but that code will make my app crash. because at first run StartingActivity does not have any intent to receive (as its the first activity launched)

Comment: no, it is nothing like this. It will receive intent as well as the values you are passing in bundle..the reason of crash is something else..

Comment: that cleared the problem thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad way to this. You should go back to basics. Workflow should go like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, YourNextActivity.class);
i.putExtra("varName", variable);
startActivity(i);
```

Then to get the value in YourNextActivity:

```
boolean defaultValue = false;
boolean varName = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("varName",defaultValue)
```

Comment: i have i have tried that. if do this my application crashes, because Activity1 is calling the launching activity of my app